# how to securely perform authorization to cloudant directly from web browsers

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, authorization, cloudant

I am planning to build an office extension application ( more or less a HTML5 application). The most valuable part of the application is the content provided by the application, so content information must be securely kept in a database. anyone trying to access the content must prove their identities by showing their usernames and passwords.

I have a Cloudant database named "_users" which stores all the users login information such as usernames and passwords, and another Cloudant database named "_contents" which stores all the content information.

When the users trying to access the "_content" database with their web browsers, the application will ask users to login. After successful matching this user's credentials with data in "_users" database, this user then have access to "_content" database.

the Ideal case for me is, the login and authorization process can be done using only web browser and Cloudant databases. I don't want to have any "middle person"(a web server running nodejs for instance) in between. How can I do this.

OK,here are some problems I can not solve.

1. When a user trying to establish connection with Cloudant databases, an API key must be provided. Ok, I can generate a API key which is permitted to read "_users" database, and give this API key to a user.a user may connect to "_users"  with this key, but does this mean with this API key, any user can read all the data in "_users" database? This would be a disaster.
2. if the above problem can be solved, how to perform authorization? Should I kept generating APIs for every users and delete them later? At what moment should I do the delete action?

Comment: I this is possible. Can you please clarify a few things, so that we can help answer your question? The office extension application is HTML5, however does it use a web server? Or is it some kind of embedded application running inside Office or something?

Comment: Also, can you please clarify: Are you using the `_users` database for your own application? Have you been using this with Apache CouchDB? Normally, Cloudant does not use the `_users` database, so I want to know if you are transitioning from CouchDB to Cloudant, or if you have been reading CouchDB documentation, or anything like that. Thanks again!

Comment: @JasonSmith, office extension application is essentially HTML5 webpages opened by Microsoft Office Word embedded browser, and the webpages are served on servers ( i chose nodejs on bluemix), all the normal browser-->server stuff can also be done here.

Comment: @JasonSmith, I am still new to NOSQL. I found Cloudant NoSQL from Bluemix, so I am considering migrating from mysql to Cloudant.   I've never tried CouchDB, but I noticed Cloudant is quite similar to CouchDB and I am reading the CouchDB documentation because of the absence of a detailed Cloudant documentation. From the security section, I did see the "special" usage of "_user" database, and I am trying to find more about it. I hope to have more control of users authorization : a user can only access the database for 1 month when he/she choose to pay for 1 month. still trying to find how to do

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! For the most part, Cloudant is very similar to CouchDB; with most differences being additional features that CouchDB does not yet have. Anyway, I recommend the Cloudant guide https://docs.cloudant.com/index.html which includes a full API reference: https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, Cloudant does not support custom usernames and passwords, the `_users` database features. Instead, Cloudant allows you to create API keys, which are random strings.

I think, given your requirements, the above system will not work. But there is good news! Cloudant also supports the open source Apache CouchDB `_users` database too. I think this will work for you; however, you will need a bit of work to set it up. This solution requires your web server to do some Cloudant preparation; however when the users use the application, they can authenticate directly to Cloudant, and they can read and update documents directly, with no middle server needed.

### Enable name authentication

See the last question of the [Cloudant developer FAQ](https://cloudant.com/for-developers/faq/auth/), "Can I use CouchDB security features..."

Basically, *for each DB*, you want to PUT to `/the_db/_security`

```
{ "couchdb_auth_only": true,
  "members": {
    "names": ["user_name_1", "user_name_2", "etc."],
    "roles": []
  }
}
```

### Set up user accounts

This works according to the Apache CouchDB documentation. Basically, you need to create a document in `_users` with the username and hashed password. **Note**, Cloudant does not yet have the newer CouchDB feature where the server will automatically hash the password for you: [Cloudant auth: lacks _users database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039704/cloudant-auth-lacks-users-database)

So as the answer says, see the [CouchDB Wiki security page](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview#Generating_password_sha_.28only_applicable_for_1.1.x_and_earlier.29) about hashing passwords. You will need to find a JavaScript SHA1 implementation, such as [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#SHA-1)

### CORS

You will likely need to enable CORS, which is also described in the Cloudant documentation, the [CORS chapter](https://docs.cloudant.com/cors.html)

With all of the above things in place, you can create users (or change their passwords by updating `/_users/*` documents; and those users can log in with basic or cookie authentication, to access their databases.

Comment: "Cloudant does not yet have the newer CouchDB feature where the server will automatically hash the password for you" => That feature is in V1.2 from 2013, how is that "newer" ?